# Swift ui macOS event detect change accent color

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui, colors, appearance

[image]

Is there an event to determine the change of accent color type in the general settings?

Comment: Use case is not clear. Changing of accent color in system preferences automatically initiates view update if it is used as color, eg. in `Text("Demo").foregroundColor(.accentColor)`.

Answer (score 2):

A possible approach is to use changes in `NSUserDefaults` via `AppStorage` observer, like

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @AppStorage("AppleAccentColor") var appleAccentColor: Int = 0

    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello world!")
            .foregroundColor(.accentColor)   // << updated automatically
            .onChange(of: appleAccentColor) { _ in
                print("Side-effect is here")
                // also can be read via NSColor.controlAccentColor
            }
    }
}
```

Tested with Xcode 15 / macOS 11.5

Answer (score 1):

Here's a potentially more flexible approach you could use, for instance, with your view model:

```swift
import Combine

class SomeClass {
    var cancellable: AnyCancellable?
    
    init() {
        cancellable = NSApp.publisher(for: \.effectiveAppearance).sink { appearance in
            print(appearance.name.rawValue)
        }
    }
}
```

You might have to ensure `cancellable?.cancel()` is called so the object can be deinitialized.